# Optimal window size with Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am using `GridBagLayout` to produce my window application in `Eclipse`. I am getting a nice window in the `Desing` tab, like this:

[image]

However, when I export it into a `jar` and launch it, I get this:

[image]

My code:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestFrame extends JFrame {
    GridBagConstraints constraints;
    JTextField text0;

    public TestFrame() {
        super("Test window");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        Container container = getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        text0 = new JTextField("Some text", 20);
        constraints.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        constraints.gridx=0;
        constraints.gridy=0;
        container.add(text0, constraints);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TestFrame test = new TestFrame();
    }
}
```

Therefore, I always need to stretch the window manually to get the right size. Alternatively, I can use `setSize()` or `setMinimumSize()` in combination with `pack()` to achieve this.

The problem, however, is that `setSize()` and `setMinimumSize()` accept dimensions in pixels, which leads to two inconveniences:

1. The new optimal size must be guessed by trial and error after each change in components number or size.
2. The window size must be fit to system display settings.

Thus, the question is: is there a way to automatically calculate the optimal window size on the basis of used components in a `jar` (like it is done in the preview)?

**SOLVED:**
As pointed out by @trashgod, it was enough to move `pack()` to the end.

Comment: *"Optimal window size with Java Swing"*  `pack()` (after adding components with suitable white space).  See also [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson  I use `pack()`; however, it does not set window size in a `jar` (I get 0x0 window, which I need to stretch).

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Done!

Comment: Your example would attempt to `pack()` an empty window if `main` weren't empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Solve this go and find **container.add(text0, constraints);** below this line call **pack();** Method which was define in JFrame class.

[For more information visit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html).

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that you pack the JFrame before adding any components to it. The size of the JFrame that is needed is 0x0 because there are no components at this point. Adding components later does not change the size of the JFrame unless you set the size or call `pack()` again.

To fix this, add the `pack();` to the end of the constructor. Ex:

```
public TestFrame() {
    super("Test window");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setVisible(true);
    Container container = getContentPane();
    container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    text0 = new JTextField("Some text", 20);
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    container.add(text0, constraints);
    pack();//Moved to last line
}
```